# Flexbox: Why flex-grow doesn't work with fixed width sibling?

Tags: css, flexbox

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/xomufuyo/1/edit)

Consider the following HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">The CSS3 Flexible Box, or flexbox, is a layout mode providing for the arrangement .</div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>


.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.first {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.second {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

and the following result:

[image]

Why the first wrapper doesn't respect `.second`'s `width: 80px`?

How could I fix that **using flexbox**?

[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/xomufuyo/1/edit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `flex: 1;` instead of <s>`flex-grow: 1;`</s>

```
.first {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/limeqofo/1/edit)</kbd>

---

Also, I would like to point out that flexbox support isn't good as far as IE is concerned, so if anyones interested in a similar layout with more compatible option, than

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="first"></div>
</div>


.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.wrapper .first {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 80px;
}

.wrapper .second {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    float: right;
    background: blue;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/67Xfz/)</kbd> *(Note that I swapped the order of the `div` in the DOM)*

Comment: or `flex-shrink:0` on the second div?

Comment: @Paulie_D Even that will suffice, but this saves an extra property :)