# Responsive div with one image and one content box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive div. The main div contains 2 child divs. First child div contains couple of input boxes and second child div contains an image.

The first problem is when I resize the browser the 2nd child div which is an image falls under the first textbox and second problem is the first child div is not the same height as 2nd image div.

Html code:

```
<div class="home-login-widget">
  <div class="login-block">
    <form method="post" action="#">
      <input value="" placeholder="Username" id="username" type="text">
      <input value="" placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="hero-image">
    <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/ahcg75tsb/hero.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/d15mvusg/

Is it possible to create a background image and then resize?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This should help with the second problem https://jsfiddle.net/d15mvusg/2/

Comment: create a background image for parent div ?

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks a lot for your help.Almost there :)

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Yes. Serg has done in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the `.hero-image` div from wrapping under `.login-block` on resize, apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to both. The padding is what's causing them to wrap like that, even though one is 30% width and the other is 61% width (so, in theory, they should always be side-by-side, since the overall width is < 100%). Using `border-box` will cause them to respect the specified widths without padding or border pushing the box model beyond 100%.

To make both boxes the same height, you're going to sacrifice the width of the image, if you want it to retain it's aspect ratio. An easy way to get both boxes to be the same height is to use `display: flex;` on the parent. A good comprimise is to (as you eluded in your post) set the image as a `background-image` and use `background-size: cover;` to have it fit as best it can to whatever shape the background image container is.

```css
.home-login-widget {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-home .login-block h1 {
  clear: left;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-family: georgia;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding: 1rem 0 0 !important;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.login-block input#username {
  background: #2b2e30 url("images/login_input_username_bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top / 275px 41px;
}

.login-block input#password {
  background: #2b2e30 url("images/login_input_pwd_bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top / 275px 41px;
}

.login-block input {
  border: medium none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #9c9b9b;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 41px !important;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.login-block {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 33.3%;
  background: #323537;
}

.hero-image {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: url('https://s23.postimg.org/ahcg75tsb/hero.png') top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

.hero-image h2 {
  background: #ff2bff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 8rem;
  width: 200px;
}

#content-home .login-block h1 {
  clear: left;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-family: georgia;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding: 1rem 0 0 !important;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-home h1 {
  clear: left;
  color: #444c4c;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  padding: 0 0 46px !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 205px;
}

.login-block, .hero-image {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-login-widget">
  <div class="login-block">
    <form method="post" action="#">
      <input value="" placeholder="Username" id="username" type="text">
      <input value="" placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="hero-image">
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot for your help. I may need to put some content below the login form so that I can see the full image or may be I can add some padding below the form(if I don't have content to add) to make the image bigger I mean full size on desktop.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra I edited  my answer to get the right side to always be the same dimensions as the image, so it will display the whole thing. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: Yes that's what I am aiming for. Do you see the image now? I can't see.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra ah nevermind. I was using the [iframe video padding technique](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) to use padding as a way to force the aspect ratio of the parent element with your background-image, but didn't test it in Firefox. Worked fine in Chrome (my browser) but not in FF.

Comment: Is it that flex-grow property which works in Chrome but not in FF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387664/flexbox-why-flex-grow-doesnt-work-with-fixed-width-sibling?

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra `flex-grow` works just fine. It was assigning `height: 0; padding-top: 38%;` to that panel that has `flex-grow`. Worked in Chrome, but not in FF.

Comment: I understood.  Stack doesn't provide us with clapping icon otherwise I would have posted that :). Your answer really helped a lot. Thanks once again.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra hah! my pleasure :)

Comment: Michael, I was looking into the ipad but for some reason I can't see the image there.

Answer (score 1):

Michael has a good answer. However, if you want another option, I think creating a div just to contain an image is a bit unnecessary. In this case we could simply attach the image to the parent element as background and size appropriately.

And yeah, you should be using `border-box`. All the cool kids are doing it.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.home-login-widget {
  background: url('https://s23.postimg.org/ahcg75tsb/hero.png') no-repeat 100% 0%;
  background-size: 70%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-home .login-block h1 {
  clear: left;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-family: georgia;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding: 1rem 0 0 !important;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.login-block input#username {
  background: #2b2e30 url("images/login_input_username_bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top / 275px 41px;
}

.login-block input#password {
  background: #2b2e30 url("images/login_input_pwd_bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top / 275px 41px;
}

.login-block input {
  border: medium none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #9c9b9b;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 41px !important;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.login-block {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 30%;
  background: #323537;
}

.hero-image {
  background: url('https://s23.postimg.org/ahcg75tsb/hero.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.hero-image h2 {
  background: #ff2bff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 8rem;
  width: 200px;
}

#content-home .login-block h1 {
  clear: left;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-family: georgia;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding: 1rem 0 0 !important;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-home h1 {
  clear: left;
  color: #444c4c;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  padding: 0 0 46px !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 205px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-login-widget">
  <div class="login-block">
    <form method="post" action="#">
      <input value="" placeholder="Username" id="username" type="text">
      <input value="" placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate for your suggestion. That's a nice idea. I need to put some text as overlay on image so I think I will stick with the div containing image thing. Thanks once again for your help.